# Grep multiple patterns and print a different number of lines below each of the patterns?

Tags: awk, grep

I am trying to find a way to grep/awk multiple patterns and then print a certain number of lines below the first pattern and a certain number of lines below the second pattern. For example

```
  ....
  other lines
  ....
###Pattern 1####
line 1
line 2
line 3 
 ....
 other lines
 ....
####Pattern 2####
line 1
line 2
line 3 
line 4
 ....
 other lines
 ....
```

So what I want to do is find the two patterns in the file and print out the first pattern and the 3 preceding lines underneath, then the second pattern and the four preceding lines underneath the second pattern.

So that my desired output looks like:

```
####Pattern 1####
line 1
line 2
line 3
####Pattern 2####
line 1
line 2
line 3 
line 4
```

**Updated Desired Output**
So before I wasn't as clear I apologize, there may be multiple patterns. So what I would hope to achieve is an output that looks like the following:

```
####Pattern 1####
line 1
line 2
line 3
####Pattern 2####
line 1
line 2
line 3 
line 4
-----
####Pattern 1####
line 1
line 2
line 3
####Pattern 2####
line 1
line 2
line 3 
line 4
-----
 and so on
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doubtless some more elegant approaches, but here's one way

```
# awk '/Pattern 1/{for(c=0;c<4;c++){print;getline}}/Pattern 2/{for(c=0;c<5;c++){print;getline}}' foo
###Pattern 1####
line 1
line 2
line 3
####Pattern 2####
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
#
```

Marginally more elegant:

```
# awk '/Pattern 1/{c=4}/Pattern 2/{c=5}{while(c-->0){print;getline}}' foo
###Pattern 1####
line 1
line 2
line 3
####Pattern 2####
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
#
```

And to pop 5 hyphens under the matched set, try this

```
# awk '/Pattern 1/{c=4}/Pattern 2/{c=5}{while(c-->0){print;getline;x=1}if(x){print "-----";x=0}}' foo
###Pattern 1####
line 1
line 2
line 3
-----
####Pattern 2####
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
-----
#
```

Or for a "-----" at the very end use:

```
# awk '/Pattern 1/{c=4}/Pattern 2/{c=5}{while(c-->0){print;getline}}END{print "-----"}' foo
###Pattern 1####
line 1
line 2
line 3
####Pattern 2####
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
-----
#
```

Comment: Is there a way so that it can then print out 5 hyphens at the bottom of line 4 of pattern 2 after the while loop is done?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @steve, but I can seem to get the last option to work. The 5 hyphens at the end of each pattern works.

Comment: Added example of that final approach that uses END.  If failing to work for you, paste your command+output?

Comment: I used exactly what you had but I think the problem is there are multiple pattern 1 and pattern 2 and what I think is happening is the `END{print "----"}` is just printing that at the bottom of the output. I'll update a new desired output.

Comment: Please remove the shell prompt when posting shell code/commands. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

```sh
sed -ne'/pattern1/{:1' -e'$p;N;s/\n/&/[num]; to' -eb1 -e\} \
     -e'/pattern2/{:2' -e'$p;N;s/\n/&/[num]; to' -eb2 -e\} \
     -ed -e:o -eh      -e'y/\n-/-\n/;s/[^-]*//g' -e'H;x;p'
```

That will print as many `-`dashes following a match block as there are newlines which follow that match. And so, if you wanted 4 lines after every pattern1 match and 2 after every pattern2 match, you'd get an additional divider line printed between each block of 4 hyphens at the tail of a pattern1 block and 2 hyphens at the tail of a pattern2 block. This is all true *except* when the last line is encountered while gathering the tail for each - in that case everything between the last line and the pattern match is printed, but no hyphens are appended.

You might notice that much of the code in the above `sed` script is fairly redundant. Basically we're just implementing an identical type of loop for each possible match. It is thanks to `sed`'s very simple syntax rules, as is evinced above, that makes scripting `sed` so eminently scriptable. In other words, because `sed`'s syntax is basic, it is a simple affair to write a script which can write a `sed` script.

For example, this task might easily be parameterized to work with any number of patterns and associated follow line counts:

```sh
amatch(){  sed ${2:+"-ne$(n=0;                   \
    while  [ "$#" -gt "$((!!(n+=1)))" ];         \
    do     printf "\n/%s/{:$n\n\t%s;to\n\t%s\n}" \
                  "$1" "\$p;N;s/\n/&/$2" "b$n";  \
           shift 2;                              \
    done;  printf "\nd;:o\n\t%s\n\t%s\n\tH;x;p"  \
                  'h;y/\n-/-\n/' 's/[^-]*//g'    \
)"}; }
```

So long as `amatch()` is called with 2 or more parameters, it will build out a `sed` script just like the one above, and write a loop for each pair.

So it first builds and prints a `sed` script in a subshell, and afterward `sed` runs it against stdin.

So when I do:

```sh
seq 30 | amatch \[45] 5 1$ 2
```

The shell's while loop assembles and prints out to the command substitution a script that looks like:

```sh
/[45]/{:1
    $p;N;s/\n/&/5;to
    b1
}
/1$/{:2
    $p;N;s/\n/&/2;to
    b2
}
d;:o
    h;y/\n-/-\n/
    s/[^-]*//g
    H;x;p
```

And `sed` evaluates that against stdin and prints...

```
1
2
3
--
4
5
6
7
8
9
-----
11
12
13
--
14
15
16
17
18
19
-----
21
22
23
--
24
25
26
27
28
29
-----
```

Comment: what do the N and num represent in this part of the sed command: `-e'$p;N;s/\n/&/[num];`?

Comment: @pdm - `N` is the `sed` command for appending the `N`ext line to pattern-space, as delimited by a `\n`ewline character. Each time we do `N` our pattern-space `\n`ewline count is incremented by one. So we loop over it until we have `[num]` `\n`ewlines. The `[num]` as written is a syntax error - the intention is that you should replace that with an actual number. Or else use `amatch()`.

Comment: Is there anything else I would need to add to this sed command other than the value for num? I tried running it and it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: @pdm - you would have to change the values for *`pattern[12]`* - but why not just use the shell function? You can just copy+paste it into your terminal, and afterward just run it as `amatch` *`pattern count`*